# Question regarding power rule and quotient rule derivatives

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

If we are taking the derivative of:

$$\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + C$$

Is this power rule, or quotient rule? What is the derivative of this expression

This is for the derivation of the integration rule of powers

Comment: The interesting thing is that you can use either rule and still obtain the same answer, but that's overkill because all you need to differentiate is the x in the numerator...the derivative of C is zero

Comment: Why can i use power? isnt this quotient? since we have a fraction

Comment: You can write the denominator in the numerator to a negative power, hence you can use power rule, the complication is that you then have to use chain rule. But there isn't any need for those rules as you have a constant times a function of x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, note that if $f(x)=\displaystyle\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$, then $$ f'(x)=\left(\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C\right)'=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(x^{n+1}\right)'=\frac{x^{n+1-1}}{n+1}=\frac{x^{n}}{n+1}$$

In our case, $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n+1}$ is a *constant*. It's not a *function* (note that the value of $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n+1}$ does not depend of $x$).

The *quotient rule* is used for functions like $f(x)=\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{x+4}$ - note that both the numerator and the denominator depend on $x$.

Comment: You forgot to bring down the power before subtracting

Comment: The derivative is $x^n$